# How to use two stepdefinitions.ts files in different folder locations in a cypress project?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

```
"main": "index.js",
 "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
 "step_definitions": "src/shared/support/step_definitions/"
 }
}
```

This is how it is written in the package.json. Is there any way I add another .ts file of another location, so that when a feature file is running, it will check both stepdefinitions files for automated implementation?

**Edit**: I also need to know whether there is any other preprocessor that allows me to include & specify stepdefinitions file in two different folder locations.

That is,

Instead of `src/shared/support/step_definitions/` I need to specify two locations where cypress can look for step definitions while running the tests. Is there any preprocessors available which allows it?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation here: https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#cypress-configuration, I think you want to add '"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false' to your package.json. That looks like it'll treat all step definitions as global.

Comment: Even though, it looks for step defs inside the mentioned folder only right?

Comment: gsw615 please respond.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, Did you find a solution or workaround for this? i am too need to follow the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to have
src/shared/support/folder_a_step_definitions_

and
src/shared/support/folder_b_step_definitions/

why don't you do
src/shared/support/step_definitions/folder_a
src/shared/support/step_definitions/folder_a

and setup the preprocessor to look for the step_definitions recursively here -

src/shared/support/step_definitions/

Comment: Inside "src/shared/support/step_definitions/" , if I put two seperate ts files, it will be working fine. My point here is I need to put the second stepdefinitions.ts file inside "src/abcfolder/support/stepdefinitions/" .

Comment: Why because, I need to split step definitions which are unique for two different sub projects under a same project.